# Create a propType that can receive a random name

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-proptypes

I have a component that receives any prop that contains '**data-** whatever'. For example, data-test, data-test2..

```
<NotificationComponent id={'ID'} data_test={data}></NotificationsComponent>
```

The component works correctly, but I need to know how to declare a prop in **propTypes** that name will be the name that recieved, at first it will be "undefined".

The component works correctly, but I need to know how to declare a prop in **propTypes**. That name will be the name it received by props ('**data-** whatever'). At first it will be "undefined."

I have tried the following

```
class NotificationsComponent extends Component {

render() {
    store.addNotification({
        title: 'Title',
        message: 'Message',
        type: 'danger',                     
        container: 'top-right',                  
        animationIn: ["animated", "fadeIn"],     
        animationOut: ["animated", "fadeOut"],   
        dismiss:{
                    showIcon: true,
                    duration: 8000,
                    onScreen: true
                }         
    });
    return (
        <div>
            <ReactNotifications />
        </div>
    );
}

NotificationsComponent.propTypes = {
    id: PropTypes.string,

    //In the next propType is my problem
    //The customProp must change the name by the prop it receive
    customProp: function customProp(props, propName, componentName) {
    const key  = Object.keys(props).find(propKey => {
        if (['id'].includes(propKey)
          || (/^data_.+/.test(propKey))) {
          return false;
        }
        return true;
      });
    if (key) {
        return new Error(
            'Invalid prop `' + key + '` supplied to' +
            ' `' + componentName + '`. Validation failed.'
        );
    }
    }
};

export default NotificationsComponent;
```

but it is not correct.

Any ideas?

Thanks for you help.

Comment: Why its an object? I think name would be a string

Comment: Because it's a variable that contains a dictionary.
data-test = {
            title: 'Title', 
            message: 'Message', 
            ...
        };

Answer (score 0):

```
const key = Object.keys(props).find(propKey => {
      if (['id'].includes(propKey)
        || (/^data_.+/.test(propKey))) {
        // console.log(propKey);
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    });

    if (key) {
      return new Error(
        'Invalid prop `' + key + '` supplied to' +
        ' `' + componentName + '`. Validation failed.'
      );
    }
```

Firstly I am sorry I was unclear in my previous answer. Secondly the regex was incorrect. In your case you can iterate through all props and check for your random prop.

Comment: Please edit your answer and add some context by explaining how your answer solves the problem, instead of posting code-only answer. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/25089696)

Comment: Ok, I tried to explain something better with the full example

Comment: Thanks for your help elvis_ferns. But I continue with the problem -> TypeError: Unexpected keyword argument `data_test`
Allowed arguments: customProp, id <-

Comment: `/^data-.+` should be `/^data_.+` then